# How to extract fitted values from a pspline fit in R?

Tags: r, model, spline, smoothing

How to extract fitted values from a pspline fit in R?

I tried fitted.values and fitted. It returns NULL. But the plot is coming perfect.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  Which package you used?

Comment: run `str(pspline.fit.result)` and see what you get

Comment: I tried `str(psline.fit.result)` and my model object is named as model. So, I tried `str(model.fit.result)`. Both returns "Error in str(model.fit.result) : object 'model.fit.result' not found". @chinsoon12

Comment: what is the name of the variable output from your pspline function?

Comment: I gave `model <- smooth.pspline(x, y, spar=5)`. If I print `model`, it gives the details of `spar, gcv, cv, df`. I plotted `model` simply with `plot(model, type = 'l')`. It gives proper graph. Now I want to extract the data that the graph gave me.